# Why does bundle exec puma fail with a Gemfile syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, capistrano3, puma

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 4 app with capistrano 3 to Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using the `capistrano3-puma` gem to handle configuring puma, but when it tries to `bundle exec puma` I get this error:

```
Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)
/srv/photo_album/releases/20140607043918/Gemfile:41: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
...sprockets_better_errors', git: 'git@github.com:RobinClowers/...
```

I'm able `bundle exec rails` just fine from this machine just fine, so I think there is something else going on. That error looks like ruby 1.8 trying to parse 1.9 hash syntax...

Comment: Please post your full Gemfile

Comment: Here is a gist of my Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/RobinClowers/f19cf819d2fb34ff89e1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I accidentally installed puma with the system ruby (which is 1.8.7), and I had not run `bundle install` yet, so there was no 2.1.1 version install for it to find.